# Reformat a timestamp

Tags: php, time, format

I have a timestamp that looks like this `2018-09-18T21:49:16Z` from an API. I need to reformat the timestamp to appear in `09-18-2018 @ 21:49:16`. How can I do this in php?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert one date format into another in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using [`DateTime::format()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php):

```
$dateTime = "2018-09-18T21:49:16Z";
$DateTimeFormat = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z", $dateTime);
echo $DateTimeFormat->format("m-d-Y @ H:i:s");
// 09-18-2018 @ 21:49:16
```

You'll have to convert your date and time string (`2018-09-18T21:49:16Z`) to a `DateTime` object using [`DateTime::createFromFormate()`](https://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).

Answer (score 0):

The PHP datetime suite is your friend.

```
$mytime = new DateTime('2018-09-18T21:49:16Z');
echo $mytime->format('m-d-Y @ H:i:s');
```

Which results in:

> 09-18-2018 @ 21:49:16